# CONTAINS in SQL 2000

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a table 'Asset' with a column 'AssetDescription'. Every row of it has some group of words/sentences, seprated by comma.

> row1: - flowers, full color, female, Trend
>   row2:- baby smelling flowers, heart

Now if a put a search query like:-

```
select * from Asset where contains(AssetDescription,'flower')
```

It returns nothing.

I have one more table 'SearchData' with column 'SearchCol', having similar rows as mentioned above in table 'Asset'. Now if a put a search query like:-

```
select * from SearchData where contains(SearchCol,'flower')
```

It returns both the rows.

QUESTION:-

1. Why first query doesn't return any result, but second one does correctly.
2. If 'Full Text Search' has something to do with 1st ques, than what to do regarding  that. As I'm using SQL server 2000.

Comment: What is the question? Did the second query not work for you?

Comment: @Benoit - Its SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CONTAINS requires a full text search index, and for full text search indexing to be enabled.
LIKE doesn't require full text search.

The advantage of using CONTAINS over LIKE is that CONTAINS is more flexible and potentially a lot faster.  LIKE may require a full table scan depending how you use it.

From the [SQL Server docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

> In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works
>   on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to
>   query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large
>   amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent
>   full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions
>   of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text
>   query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending
>   on the number of rows that are returned.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. But please find the updated question and see if you can help me regarding the same

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't change a question after it has been answered.  You should ask another one.

Comment: Ok I will ask another. Actually, I thought of asking another one, but I thought moderaters would delete that considering that as a similar post.

Answer (score 4):

Your first query isn't matching anything because you're not using a wildcard character. Your rows contain the word 'flowers' whereas you're searching for rows containing 'flower'. You would need to change the query to:

```
select * from asset where contains(AssetDescription, 'flower*')
```

Comment: There is also the issue that the two queries are not logically the same. The former won't match "sunflower" while the latter will.

Comment: @Justin -  Even this did not help. Please see the updated question, if U can help anything on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your full-text index. Could be that it's out of date and hence not finding them when you use CONTAINS.

Comment: How to do that in SQL server 2000. But if it is at all out of date. Then how its working properly with one tablebut with it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, to use `contains` with a word prefix, you use a wildcard.

More here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx